# cannot turn on dev hub and create scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, dev-hub

I download the developer edition and log in with a partner license given by Salesforce to my company. However, I cannot follow the partner development guide when it mentions dev hub and scratch orgs.

This is what happens:

1. When I type Dev Hub in the quick find search box and click on the dev hub link shown, I get the error message: You can't enable Dev Hub in a Developer Edition org with a registered namespace.
2. I follow this guide to turn on Dev Hub:
   https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev/sfdx_app_dev_setup_dx

with the command:
'''
sfdx auth:web:login -d -a DevHub
'''

The command completes without complaining

But when I go on with creating a scratch org following this tutorial:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev/sfdx_app_dev_create_app

The following command, when run in the "geolocation" folder created following the guide:
'''
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a GeoAppScratch
'''
gives me the error:

ERROR running force:org:create:  The requested resource does not exist

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> When I type Dev Hub in the quick find search box and click on the dev hub link shown, I get the error message: You can't enable Dev Hub in a Developer Edition org with a registered namespace.

This appears to be the root of your problems, and suggests you may be working in the wrong org. If the org you're logged in to has a registered namespace, it's likely either a packaging org for a first-generation package or the namespace org for a second-generation package. The packaging org is the "golden master" org for a first-generation package and must be protected to ensure the integrity of your company's package. It can't be used as your Dev Hub, and if you're not a package developer you shouldn't have access to it. If the org is the namespace org for a second-generation package, it needs to be *linked to* your Dev Hub (using the Namespace Registries tab in the Dev Hub) but cannot itself be the Dev Hub.

Most partners should be using their Partner Business Org (PBO) as the Dev Hub due to the higher limits provided by that org. Work with your colleagues or Partner Support to determine where your PBO is.

The subsequent errors you're encountering are because Dev Hub is not turned on in the org that you've named `DevHub` in the SFDX keychain.